# Why it is on topic and highly upvoted to just ask for a list of features of a language?

Tags: discussion, scope

Why this question is not being closed [What are the new features in C++17?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38060436/2003898)
?

Asking for features of a language is asking for a list of features what is AFAIK a simple example of what had to be considered as too broad.
Especially this post motivates to just list the features without further explaining them. Anything being explicit enough would be simply a copy of the standard. Anything else would just be incomplete and maybe wrong.

So there is no use of this at all.

It is as far I could judge about just a question that should be closed as beeing too broad, selfanswered by an link only styl of feature-listed answer that requires you to look up the standard anywaym or risk beeing misinformed.

So why did the moderation decide it to be on-topic?

Would it also be ok to ask on SO: "What are the features provided by language X?" Which is without any doubt the same kind of question.

Comment: I agree.  That's a horrible abuse of SO.  For every stupid language update I could do the same bloody thing.  "What are the new features of C# 6.0?" and copypasta the answer from MSDN.  It's a joke, and mods should do something about it.  But these C++ tag trolls just gotta have things their way.  (*runs for the bunker*)